# Display template not accepting list<object> from another property on the model?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model that looks like this:

```
 public class WorksheetViewModel() {
     public Worksheet Worksheet {get; set;}
     // ... more properties
 }

 public class Worksheet() {
     public List<LineItem> LineItems {get; set;}
     public Loan Loan {get; set; }
     // ... more properties
 }

 public class LineItem() {
     // ... some properties
 }

 public class Loan() {
     public List<LoanField> Fields {get; set;}
     // ... more properties
 }

 public class LoanField() {
     // ... some properties
 }
```

In my view I have the following:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Worksheet.LineItems)   // this works great
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Worksheet.Loan.Fields) // this throws exception
```

I'm getting an exception that looks like this:

```
 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataContracts.LoanField]',
 but this dictionary requires a model item of type
 'DataContracts.LoanField'.
```

The display templates for both collections are similar in that both reference on the model they are are showing:

Working template:

```
 @model DataContracts.LineItem
 @Html.Label(Model.ItemType.Description) : @Model.RecipientEmployee.FullName<br />
```

Not working template:

```
 @model DataContracts.LoanField
 @Html.Label(Model.FieldName) : @Model.FieldValue<br />
```

Since the first template correctly accepts a List of LineItem objects then it would seem that the second template would behave the same way, but clearly its not in this case.

Anyone have an idea why the template is complaining about the list and a way to get around it?

Comment: It might possibly be due to the object being nested one more level than the other list.  Not that this is valid for your model, but just to try, what if you move the `public List<LoanField> Fields {get; set;}` property to `Worksheet` so then you can render it as `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Worksheet.Fields)`.

Comment: Actually I think my above postulation might be inline with the error you are receiving as well.

Comment: @asymptoticFault, there's really no way for me to change the models here... the way in which its populated would require some serious changes that would really not make any sense. However, I did try nesting my display templates (making a "Loan" template, then having the Loan template call the Fields template) but that had the same exception.

Comment: @asymptoticFault, for the heck of it I added a property to the view model that returns the list of LoanField from the Loan object. This has no effect, resulting in the same exception.

Comment: I see.  Yeah I wasn't suggesting you permanently change it, just temporarily to try it but sounds like it's more trouble than it's worth.  I did see some approaches in searching around that suggested what you said you just tried but they didn't seem promising and as you said it didn't work anyway.  I've had trouble using the helpers on complex objects as well, seems to be sort of a limitation but I'll keep thinking and looking around to see if we can figure this out.

Comment: I found the issue... its embarrassing but I'll post the answer just in case somebody else looking for that exception message has another thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many whacky tricks unlikely to work I decided to try changing the name of the template... and it worked.

The problem was an initial misunderstanding in the convention being followed. When I first created a display template I named it after the property name is was being displayed for... in this case "Fields".

Silly me... I assumed that MVC would be smart enough to use the @model to resolve the type. I thought this assumption was confirmed when I saw that you can pass in a template name as one of the parameters in Html.DisplayFor().

However, as most of you can probably guess by now, the template must be named the same as the datatype its displaying (the very same type which is clearly spelled out in the @model statement).  Once I changed the name of the template everything worked fine.